# how to Set Default values in interactive grid columns based on selecting apex items

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I am working on Oracle Apex. I have a doubt. how can we give default values to interactive grid column from apex items. Below i provided sample layout of my application.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I did a quick test on the EMP table.

- Create an editable IG on EMP with query `SELECT * FROM emp`.
- Make EMPNO the primary key column
- create a hidden item P1_JOB with source type "Static Value" and value "ANALYST"
- For IG column JOB set the default type to "Item" and the "Item" attribute to P1_JOB
- Run the IG, click "Add Row". The new row has a default value ANALYST in the job column.

For a more complex business case you probably need a computation or page process to set the default value, but this example shows the most simple case.